# Redux spread InitialState pattern

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers, redux-reducers

Recently I stumbled upon the codebase where every reducer looks like the following. I guess they are spreading `initialState` to get rid of some 'leftover' nested state when reducer initialises, but is it meaningful?

```
const initialState = {...}

const reducer = (state = {...initialState}, action) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: no need to use spread operator, anyway redux won't override the initial values

Answer (score 0):

If your reducer doesn't violate immutability principle, spreading an initialState does not make any sense, since reducer returns a new state (e.g. using aforementioned spread operator) on every action anyway.